# Getting a single record from the SQL database with bind_param

Tags: php, mysql

I am not sure what to do as I am fairly new to PHP still and have looked through several places and tutorials but nothing seems to get me what I want from the database. I am just looking to return a make of a vehicle from my database with a variable Id.

```
$query = "SELECT id make From myVins WHERE id = ?";

$myq = $dbc->prepare($query);

$id = $_GET['id'];

*//making sure I have the right id*

echo $id;

$myq->bind_param('i', $id);

$myq->execute();

$res = $myq->fetch() ;

echo $res;
```

Like I mentioned I am fairly new so I am not sure if I am even close. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the single record from the database you have to make use of the Query with the `where` clause.

**Where Clause Definition:**

We can use a conditional clause called `WHERE` clause to filter out results. Using `WHERE clause`, we can specify a selection criteria to select required records from a table.

The WHERE clause works like an if condition in any programming language. This clause is used to compare given value with the field value available in MySQL table. If given value from outside is equal to the available field value in MySQL table, then it returns that row.

Here is the list of operators, which can be used with WHERE clause.

Assume field A holds 10 and field B holds 20, then:

[image]

Now i feel like you can understand the Where clause in Detail.

**Here on i shall explain how to retrieve the single record from the table using another name**

`SQL Aliases`

SQL aliases are used to give a database table, or a column in a table, a temporary name.

Replace:

```
$query = "SELECT id make From myVins WHERE id = ?";
```

By

```
$query = "SELECT `make` as id FROM `myVins` WHERE `id` = ?";
```

Now from the above query the make field from the table will be retrieved using the id Aliases name. Hence the data can be displayed using the aliases name from the query output that you get.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

**Or else you want to retrieve both the variable you can use this.**

Replace:

```
$query = "SELECT id make From myVins WHERE id = ?";
```

By

```
$query = "SELECT `id`,`make` FROM `myVins` WHERE `id` = ?";
```

Hope so my explanation will be clear and you could go miles from here on.

Answer (score -1):

Please change your query.

```
$query = "SELECT id make From myVins WHERE id = ?";
```

with

```
$query = "SELECT id, make From myVins WHERE id = ?";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply to him. But he does not want to retrieve both the data. he just want to retrieve the make information with the variable id as per his question. As per your code it will retrieve both the ID as well as the make. better to use alias name for make and can crack on.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Please read this carefully you will get your replay " I am just looking to return a make of a vehicle from my database with a variable Id."